# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: error in xlrd

Tags: python, xlrd

**Language: Python-3.7.3**, **xlrd**: 1.2.0

I am getting the below error while printing excel value as below.

**Code:**

```
import xlrd


class ExcelOperations():

    def open_excel(self, filepath):
        return xlrd.open_workbook(filepath)

    def get_column_values(self, filepath):
        return self.open_excel(filepath).sheet_by_index(0).cell_value(1, 0)


run = ExcelOperations()
print(run.get_column_values(run.get_column_values(localfilepath)))
```

**Excel value**

```
sheet1, A1(test),A2(test123)
```

**Error:-**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'test123'
```

Code looks to be correct and unsure why this error is coming out. Can someone assist me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace

```py
print(run.get_column_values(run.get_column_values(localfilepath)))
```

with

```py
print(run.get_column_values(localfilepath))
```